# Java - Make FPS work properly

Tags: java, performance, frames, frame-rate

I just made a working Pong game in Java but I have some questions about how the FPS works. Currently, the game runs as fast as the computer can handle it and if I run the game on a faster computer, then the game will speed up way faster than normal. I solved this by adding a timer to prevent the game from running too fast:

```
timer = new Timer(5, this);
timer.start();
```

However, because of the timer, the FPS cannot go over a specific limit no matter how fast the computer is. When the FPS drops, instead of slowing down the program, I want it to "lag behind" like in a real computer game. How do I do this? I want to force the game to run at a certain speed so the FPS will drop instead of the program slowing down.

My FPS counter currently looks like this:

```
if(System.currentTimeMillis() - time >= 1000){
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        fps = newfps;
        newfps = 0;
    }
    else{
        newfps++;
    }
    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 25));
    g.drawString(fps + "", 5, 22);
```

Please tell me if I am unclear about my question.

Comment: what do you mean, "lag behind"? would you like the drawing to happen slower than the game is running?

Comment: If the FPS drops for some reason, I want the program to skip frames instead of slowing down the entire program. I want to stop the program from slowing down or running too fast.

Comment: The FPS is eventually going to be limited by your display hardware. Take a look at implementing VSynch in your game so you render data at an optimal rate for your GPU and monitor. In addition, make sure you are using double buffering - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html

Comment: The frequency of calls to paint methods is not a reliable indicator of frames per second.  The system can paint a component for many reasons.  Also, it may invoke paint methods multiple times for a single display operation.  It’s also possible for multiple frames to be coalesced into a single paint call.

Comment: @MichaelPeacock That sounds interesting but I don't want to limit the game to 60. I want it to show the exact fps as the computer can handle.

Answer (score 0):

At its core, this is a threading issue. Use (at least) one thread to do all calculations for your game, and another to render. That means that the rendering cycles would be independent from the background processing, and shouldn't have the ability to slow them down.

Comment: I never learned about making threads, I can try to find a tutorial about how to do this, thank you.

Comment: Sure thing. if my answer helped, please remember to mark it